# JavaScript class/object detect or observe changes

Tags: javascript, callback, observers

I have the following javascript class. Is there a way to detect a change in any of the class properties, like a callback on whenever firstName value gets assigned or current value for firstName changes?

```
class User
{
    constructor(firstName,lastName,dob){
      this.firstName=firstName;
      this.lastName=lastName;
      this.dob=dob;
   }
}
```

Comment: [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set), and a bunch of similar things, e.g. proxies.

Comment: @ASDFGerte is there a way to add an event that will watch for changes at class level "User". Something like whenever any of the property changes an event User.ObjectModified() is triggered? I can do this via individual properties, looking for a better way.

Comment: [handler.get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get), [handler.set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set)